# Why should we make our POJO's Serializable in Java?

Tags: java, serialization

I've seen a lot of questions on how to Serialize POJO's in java using different frameworks, but I wanted to really understand the need of making our POJO's Serializable in the first place. You use JavaScript to handle the POJO objects or Spring or any other framework - why is it that we always have to make our POJO's `Serializable` ?

Is it something that has to be done on a **GOOD PRACTICE** or a **BEST PRACTICE**?

If it is not the case, what is the advantage that we would be able to leverage by Serializing POJO classes?

There are a couple of threads that discuss about this, but I'm not really satisfied with the explanation / answers!

Can anyone here, shed some light on this concept please?

Comment: We simply serialize the POJOs to keep its states across many instances or for later use

Comment: "why is it that we always have to serialize our POJO's" we don't. I never do.

Comment: Apologize, I should've been more specific about the question - I'm not referring to every other POJO that we create, but only those which makes a lot of sense to the business entities and business logic!

Comment: 'We' usually don't, but the container does, or a framework, as part of a session or view or request scope. Did you mean why should we *make* our POJOs `Serializable`?

Comment: Yes @EJP, that was the question - Why should we make our POJO's Serializable?

Comment: There is an *enormous* difference between 'serializing our POJOs' and 'making our POJOs `Serializable`', and the answer to 'why is it that we always have to make our POJO's Serializable?' is that we don't. Pointless and poorly expressed question and title.

Comment: I'm not sure, why you term this as pointless - whereas the question was genuine to check the need of Serialization, at least in the scenario that I mentioned later (I didn't want to go with a lengthy question, at first). I apologize for the "poorly expressed question" as you state!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You serialize POJO's when you usually need to:

1. Transmit them through some medium (Web Service, etc)
2. Store them on some medium. (This in turn devolves into how you are going to store them: XML, binary, etc).

You do not always have to serialize them, it depends on what ever it is you are doing.

For instance, if you have a web application with the concept of a `User` object, wherein a user has a user name, and  maybe some preferences it might not make sense to make that class serializable. However, if you expose a web service through which 3rd parties can extract user information, then that class would need to be serializable so that it can be transmitted to said 3rd parties.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, @npinti! Makes a lot of sense now! Can I bring in a scenario of this being used in a Clustered APP & WEB environment - where such serialized data be replicated on both the APP servers to ensure that the requests are handled promptly if any one of the APP server goes down? Is this a scenario where we could vouch on to Serialization?

Comment: @BPavanKumar: From what I am understanding, you would need to transmit and store PJO's so that they can be deserialized and maintained. In that case serialization would work. I would however recommend you look to see if there is any 3rd party library which handles this for you (synchronization of POJO's between App servers) since it can get quite complicated.

Comment: Please clarify the difference between 'serialize our POJOs', which is what you said, and 'making our POJOs `Serializable`', which is what you *appear* to mean, and which in any case is what the question is about.

Comment: You've got my question right. Thanks again for your tip! if you know of any such 3rd party library or framework, please do suggest!

Comment: @EJP: Did you by chance downvote the answer because of the ambiguity of the OP's question or is it because there is something wrong with it? (Just trying to see what changes I can make, if any to make the answer better).

Comment: You don't have any information about who downvoted your answer, and you still haven't made the requested clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Serialization is needed when you have to convert the Object to byte Stream.

Byte Streaming is needed when you transmit the object with other applications or when you have to store that object.

So if you are using other formats like JSON for passing data, you won't need to serialize your objects.